# Why is attachmentId missing in payload/parts/body from certain emails?

Tags: gmail-api

I'm using the gmail API to first generate a list of all attachments, and then download the attachments on demand.

I'm basically calling `GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{ID}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` on all message ids that have an attachment, and then grabbing all the attachmentIds to use with the messages.attachments API later. This works for the majority of my attachments, but I notice for certain emails, the attachment ID is missing.

Heres an example response (with certain parts omitted) from such one of those emails:

```
{
 "id": "114fda8b3fe57cb1",
 "threadId": "114fda8b3fe57cb1",
 "labelIds": [
  "INBOX"
 ],
 "snippet": "",
 "historyId": "1027074",
 "payload": {
  "mimeType": "multipart/mixed",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
  ],
  "body": {
   "size": 0
  },
  "parts": [
   {

   },
   {
    "partId": "1",
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "filename": "IMG_3746.JPG",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "image/jpeg; name=\"IMG_3746.JPG\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
      "value": "base64"
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Disposition",
      "value": "attachment; filename=\"IMG_3746.JPG\""
     },
     {
      "name": "X-Attachment-Id",
      "value": "f_1ydodxn"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 447292    <------ Here is where I would expect attachmentId to be...
    }
   },
   {

   }
  ]
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 2873869
}
```

Here's what the parts/body looks like from a response from a message that has everything I expected:

```
"body": {
"attachmentId": "ANGjdJ9CRk8VcuxPzOMnGhFQdJpB6vc7xNAZTw5Gav3jZRQkEi3lRvELnjUTEqQtpiJDkKx8IR3qEOyT0wW6LD_tQ3NvPWDucURPaW0xUBJm8gwP-De9hOt7DbciRdfYCX79JWoHtGS2cooTzpAfZwYXc2lmcjCeL_SvgCZAtIEOVs45atTOsx9BCb02aJzNAvga2f3OdsBNbUkCyyZWQZGB0bHQf4q30BmoDFLrBhq67k3f5VOpOxsFl4QDLS5Md-JxhbQ1qsFk_usEUvcOqFsNgckmtj6y0zrKyDDc8g",
"size": 536
}
```

I can't use GET messages/attachments without the attachmentId... whats going on? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you use this form to let us know an email address and message id where this consistently happens?  http://goo.gl/NCpJXf  That will help us debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Eric, any ideas?

Comment: Willy can you confirm whether it's still happening or not and if it's resolved accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks Eric! That fixes several of my emails that were missing attachments. Theres one specific one that still has this issue though, I'll use the same form from above to give you the ID. (This email gives raw data instead of attachmentID, so at least I can get what I want, admittedly in an inconsistent manner).

Comment: One of the two (data or attachmentId) is always expected for each part.  So that's working as intended.  If the attachment is small we just include it inline, if it's large we send out an attachmentId to retrieve it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that was an issue with some older attachments.  Should be resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using API in Python) the `attachmentId` was never in the body.

I went here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get

to use "Try this method" window

and I found the `attachmentId` in `parts[1].body`

[image: parts]